# Only select first instance of nth-child with multiple results

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm using a webpage builder that is limiting my control over certain aspects of design. Currently it pre-format all my div elements to live within a container among other things. The stylesheet has a max-width on all containers and I want to remove this for just the first container.

The page looks something like this (simplified)

```
...
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="myClass" id="1">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="myClass2" id="2">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="myClass3" id="3">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The CSS I want to change is for .container but I only want to change it for #1. Right now I have:

```
<style>
div.container:nth-child(5) {max-width: none !important;}
</style>
```

But that selects *all* the containers on the page so #1, #2, #3, etc. all have no max-width.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `section:first-of-type > div:first-of-type`

Comment: The selector shown would not select anything from the HTML given, since there is only one container per section.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to change the width of the container in the first section.

```
<style>
    section:first-of-type>.container {max-width: none !important;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position among a group of siblings

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

try solving with a custom class